# Which is the correct way to use System.Convert.ToInt64 function?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have following code:

```
 Dim len As Int32 = 1000
 Dim rdlen As Int64 = 2000000000000
 Dim totlen As Int64
```

Which example is the correct way to use **System.Convert.ToInt64** function?

**Example one:**

```
 totlen = System.Convert.ToInt64(rdlen + len)
```

**Example two:**

```
 totlen = rdlen + System.Convert.ToInt64(len)
```

Comment: There's no need to do either. `totlen = rdlen + len` will work just fine because there is a built-in implicit conversion from `Int32` to `Int64`.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: Mixing data type (Int32 with Int64) is OK?

Comment: Widening conversions (i.e. from `Int32` to `Int64`) are perfectly safe because it's impossible to lose information. Every `Int32` can be expressed as an `Int64`. Going the other way, however, is a *narrowing conversion*, and you can lose information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both examples are correct. At least in c#.

When A and B is of different integer type, compiler should convert both of them to the same type in order to do A+B. So it converts both to Int64 before computing A+B.

Answer (score 2):

Both expressions will evaluate to the same thing.

There is an [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) between `Int32` and `Int64`, so even the following works:

```
totlen = rdlen + len
```

Answer (score 0):

It works either way, and it works without the conversion also, as the 32 bit integer will be widened to work with the 64 bit integer.

You shouldn't use the `Convert` class to do such conversion anyway, you should just use the cast syntax.

If you want to show in the code exactly what's happening, or if you want to make sure that it really happens the way you indend it, you cast the 32 bit integer to 64 bits before the addition:

```
totlen = rdlen + (Int64)len;
```

It will however produce the exact same code as this, as the 32 bit integer will be implicitly converted:

```
totlen = rdlen + len;
```